"Open in firefox" should save file in temporary folder but saves it in my download folder
When I select to open a file in Firefox (for example a pdf) it automatically saves the file in my download folder.
I only want this to happen if I select to download it. How can I tell firefox to save it in the temporary files as it used to do?
I could not find out how to change change this behaviour without also changing the download path for normal downloads.

After entering about:config as an url, search for
browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir
and set it to true. Now only what is selected to be downloaded will be saved in your specified download folder, while everything else will be saved in
C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp.
@K J thank you for suggesting the other question. It is similar, but missing an answer that worked. Nevertheless, it guided me in the right direction.
